# Defining finite sets in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

How can I define constant sets in Isabelle ? For example something like {1,2,3} (to give it a more interesting twist with 1,2,3 being reals), or {x \in N: x < m},  where m is some fixed number - or, perhaps more difficult, the set {N,R,C}, where N are the naturals numbers, R the real and C the complex ones.

I imagine in all cases it has to be something like

```
definition a_set :: set
  where "a_set ⟷ ??? "
```

but various attempts of replacing `???` with something correct failed.

Somehow all the tutorial I found talk about defining functions on sets - but I couldn't find simple examples like these to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

The `definition` command defines a constant. It takes a single equation with the symbol to be defined on the left-hand side, e.g. `definition "x = 5"` or `definition "f = (λx. x + 1)"`. For increased readability, function arguments can appear on the left-hand side of the equation, e.g. `f x = x + 1`.

The problem is that you're using `⟷` (the ‘if and only if’ operator, i.e. equality of Booleans). When you have Booleans, it's a good idea to use this instead of simply `=` because it saves parentheses: You can write ‘P x ⟷ x = 2 ∨ x = 5’ instead of ‘P x = (x = 2 ∨ x = 5)’. (The `=` operator binds more strongly than the logical connectives `∨` and `∧`; `⟷`, on the other hand, binds more weakly)

`⟷` is just another way of writing `=` specialised to Booleans. That means that if you're defining something that doesn't return a Boolean, `⟷` is not going to work. Just use regular `=`:

```
definition A :: "real set" where
  "A = {1, 2, 3}"
```

Or, for your other example:

```
definition B :: "complex set set" where
  "B = {ℕ, ℝ, UNIV}"
```

Note that HOL is a *typed* logic; that means that you cannot just do

```
definition a_set :: set
```

because there is no type of all sets. There is only a type of all sets whose elements have a specific type, e.g. `nat set` or `(real ⇒ real) set` or indeed `nat set set`. Just saying `set` will give you an error message ‘Could not parse type’ because `set` is a type constructor that expects one type argument and you have given it none.

Regarding the set {ℕ, ℝ, ℂ}, this is the constant `B` I defined above as an example. There is no `ℂ` in Isabelle because that is just `UNIV :: complex set`. (`UNIV` being the set of all values of the type in question). Note that the ℕ and ℝ in that case are the set of natural and real numbers *as a subset of the complex numbers*.

Comment: Great answers, thx! But somehow a slightly more complicated set definition, as `definition A :: "nat set" where  "A = {n∈ℕ . n<2}"` still doesn't work, as `value` outputs a long string of things, instead of just a number. Do you an idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: Note my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317474/isabelle-return-numbers-instead-of-sucsuc-0 This is an example where code generation fails and `value` falls back to some other method, and the output isn't terribly useful.

Comment: Even though it may well appear so sometimes, Isabelle cannot actually work magic. Evaluating an expression requires Isabelle to have *code equations* for all the constants that are involved, and since your constant involves a set comprehension over an infinite set (the natural numbers), there are no code equations available. Of course, your example is quite trivial, but the code generator doesn't *know* that.

Comment: By the way, the ℕ in there is redundant, since your set is of type `nat set` anyway, so `ℕ` is the same as `UNIV`. You could simply write: `"A = {n . n<2}"`.

Comment: The usual way to get evaluation to work in such cases is to provide a code equation, e.g. in your case `lemma A_code [code]: "A = {0, 1}" by (auto simp: A_def)`. Then `value` works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the lemma (is this the only method ? I imagine if I have a lot of sets in a proof, writing for each one a lemma to comfortable display its value at a later time, is cumbersome). Are you sure though that using `ℕ` in the definition of `A` is superfluous? Because without it, value returns an error, as in this example ``theory tmp imports Main begin
  
definition A :: "nat set"
  where "A = { n∈ℕ. n<2}"
    
value A (* Works, but weird output*)
  
definition B :: "nat set"
  where "B = { n. n<2}"
    
value B (*Wellsortedness error*)

end``

Comment: It is superfluous in the sense that they both describe the same value, but the term structure is slightly different, so perhaps normalisation by evaluation can do something in one case but not the other for technical reasons.

Comment: Things you only use once in a proof usually don't get their own definitions, and even when they do, you typically don't need to evaluate them with `value`. People don't use `value` nearly as much as beginners tend to think. If you absolutely want to get code generation working, you won't get around providing some setup consisting of code equations (like what I did) or something similar. See this manual: http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016-1/doc/codegen.pdf